# Как отправить письмо для активации аккаунта на языке клиента?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_registration', 10, 2 );
function my_registration( $user_id ) {
    // get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    // create md5 code to verify later
    $code = md5(time());
    // make it into a code to send it to user via email
    $string = array('id'=>$user_id, 'code'=>$code);
    // create the activation code and activation status
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_activated', 0);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'activation_code', $code);
    // create the url
    $url = get_site_url(). '/my-account/?act=' .base64_encode( serialize($string));
    // basically we will edit here to make this nicer
    $html = '[:en]Please click the following links[:ru]Пожалуйста, нажмите на следующие ссылки[:] <br/><br/> <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    // send an email out to user
    wp_mail( $user_info->user_email, __('Odels','text-domain') , $html);
}
```

С помощью этого кода отправлю письмо для активации аккаунта, но он должен отправляться на **языке клиента**, сейчас выводит сам шорткод(`[:en]Please click[:ru]Пожалуйста, нажмите =[:]`), а не текст перевода например(Please click the following links) для ЕN.

Как отправить письмо на языке клиента? Возможно вы знаете другие способы как это можно реализовать?

Cайт на Wordpress.
Плагин перевода q translate x

Comment: $html = do_shortcode( .... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по коду `[:en]...[:ru]...[:]` у вас шорткод. Но вы их не выполняете. Используйте функцию `do_shortcode`, чтобы выполнить все шорткоды в строке:

```
...
html = do_shortcode( '[:en]Please click the following links[:ru]Пожалуйста, нажмите на следующие ссылки[:] <br/><br/> <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>' );
...
```